# Intermittent but repeated HAL_RTC_SetDate error on STM32F4 with Mbed-OS 5

Tags: embedded, mbed, stm32f4

I have been trying to figure out what went wrong with my PCB/embedded code. The PCB is designed around STM32F407VE. set_time() is called every 5/10/20/60/120 seconds.

```
time_t et = time(NULL);
debug("%d: NTP sync started\r\n", et);
set_time(et);
```

600 seconds after the code called for the first time, I will see something like the following:

```
1587754882: NTP sync started
1587754902: NTP sync started
1587754922: NTP sync started
1587754942: NTP sync started
1587754962: NTP sync started
1587754982: NTP sync started
1587755002: NTP sync started
1587755022: NTP sync started
1587755042: NTP sync started
1587755062: NTP sync started
1587755082: NTP sync started
1587755102: NTP sync started
1587755122: NTP sync started
1587755142: NTP sync started
1587755162: NTP sync started
1587755182: NTP sync started
1587755202: NTP sync started
1587755222: NTP sync started
1587755242: NTP sync started
1587755262: NTP sync started
1587755282: NTP sync started
1587755302: NTP sync started
1587755322: NTP sync started
1587755342: NTP sync started
1587755362: NTP sync started
1587755382: NTP sync started
1587755402: NTP sync started
1587755422: NTP sync started
1587755442: NTP sync started
1587755462: NTP sync started
1587755482: NTP sync started


++ MbedOS Error Info ++
Error Status: 0x80FF0100 Code: 256 Module: 255
Error Message: Fatal Run-time error
Location: 0x8022591
Error Value: 0x0
Current Thread: main  Id: 0x20005B8C Entry: 0x801A273 StackSize: 0x2000 StackMem: 0x2000B4C0 SP: 0x2000D270 
For more info, visit: https://mbed.com/s/error?error=0x80FF0100&tgt=ARCH_MAX
-- MbedOS Error Info --
HAL_RTC_SetDate error
```

If the interval is 5 seconds, then 121th call will trigger system crash. If the interval is 2 minute, then the 6th call will trigger crash.

A few other observations:
1) This happens regardless of using LSI or LSE as source of RTC clock.
2) If I comment out set_time() then then system doesn't crash.
3) The following simple test code doesn't crash on the same PCB. But if commented out code is enabled, it will reproduce the problem.

```
    time_t et;
    printf("%d: system started\r\n", time(NULL));
    uint8_t toResetRTC = 0, toSaveFooIntoBackupRegister = 0;
    uint32_t foo = 12345;
    while (1)
    {
        toResetRTC++;
        if(toResetRTC > 4)
        {
            et = time(NULL);
            printf("%d: RTC reset started\r\n", et);
            set_time(et);
            toResetRTC = 0;
        }
        toSaveFooIntoBackupRegister++;
        if(toSaveFooIntoBackupRegister > 59)
        {
            RTC_HandleTypeDef RtcHandle;
            RtcHandle.Instance = RTC;
            HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
            HAL_RTCEx_BKUPWrite(&RtcHandle, 0, foo);
            // This following line messes up HAL_RTC_SetDate() and HAL_RTC_SetTime() when called by set_time();
            // If the following line is enabled, system crashes every 1 minute
            //HAL_PWR_DisableBkUpAccess();
            toSaveFooIntoBackupRegister = 0;
        }
        ThisThread::sleep_for(1000);
    }
```

My take is other part(s) of the code base is interfering with RTC periodically.
Could anybody offer some pointers on how to troubleshoot?

Thanks.

Update:
The first block of code that contains set_time() was called via a ticker which sources clock from HSE. When I was reviewing console output when RTC was sourced from LSI (attached below), I realized the interval has changed to 570 on the 31 first run that crashes the system. It became evident to me that crash doesn't happen because of some mysterious rhythm intrinsic to RTC but rather something outside RTC. And there is block of code that executes 600 seconds from system boot. This block code eventually leads to finding in the answer.

crash log when RTC is sourced from LSI.

```
1587760500: NTP sync started
1587760519: NTP sync started
1587760538: NTP sync started
1587760557: NTP sync started
1587760576: NTP sync started
1587760595: NTP sync started
1587760614: NTP sync started
1587760633: NTP sync started
1587760652: NTP sync started
1587760671: NTP sync started
1587760690: NTP sync started
1587760709: NTP sync started
1587760728: NTP sync started
1587760747: NTP sync started
1587760766: NTP sync started
1587760785: NTP sync started
1587760804: NTP sync started
1587760823: NTP sync started
1587760842: NTP sync started
1587760861: NTP sync started
1587760880: NTP sync started
1587760899: NTP sync started
1587760918: NTP sync started
1587760937: NTP sync started
1587760956: NTP sync started
1587760975: NTP sync started
1587760994: NTP sync started
1587761013: NTP sync started
1587761032: NTP sync started
1587761051: NTP sync started
1587761070: NTP sync started


++ MbedOS Error Info ++
Error Status: 0x80FF0100 Code: 256 Module: 255
Error Message: Fatal Run-time error
Location: 0x8022591
Error Value: 0x0
Current Thread: main  Id: 0x20005B8C Entry: 0x801A273 StackSize: 0x2000 StackMem: 0x2000B4C0 SP: 0x2000D270 
For more info, visit: https://mbed.com/s/error?error=0x80FF0100&tgt=ARCH_MAX
-- MbedOS Error Info --
HAL_RTC_SetDate error
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you increase (try doubling) the stack size?  Look in the map file generated by the linker to determine what is located at location 0x8022591.  If that address is within a function then maybe there is a bug in that function.

Comment: If the crash is as reproducible as you say then you should be able to run until just before the crash and then single step in the debugger until the crash occurs.  This can show you what is executing at the moment of the crash and then you can repeat and examine all the related variables/registers which may reveal something unexpected.  If it's helpful you may be able to set a breakpoint with a counter condition such that it doesn't break until the 120th (or whatever) time through the code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I haven't tried increasing stack size yet. I was able to identify one part of the code base whose execution correlates with the HAL_RTC_SetDate error. If I change the interval of that part of code down to 1 minute, then HAL_RTC_SetDate error happens every 1 minute right after execution of that part of code. I will post back when I understand why that happens.

Comment: That part of code involves execution of HAL_PWR_DisableBkUpAccess(); which messed up HAL_RTC_SetDate().

Comment: You have posted the code that _does not crash_ but omitted the code that _dies crash_ how are we supposed to help with that?

Comment: @ZhiyongLi Is that (the bkp access thing) the _answer_ or just supporting information. If the latter, edit the question, if it is the answer, post an answer to avoid others wasting time on this. Comments should not be used for "never mind, I've fixed it", SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum. If the solution invalidates the question, edit or delete the question.

Comment: @Clifford. The backup access restriction is the answer. I will put together an answer later. Because the reason why HAL_PWR_DisableBkUpAccess() messes SetDate() was not evident to me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was eventually tracked down to another part the code base that eventually after 3 hops calls the execution of:

```
HAL_PWR_DisableBkUpAccess();
```

I was under the impression that this line only disables access to RTC backup data registers(which is used in the code base) and backup SRAM. But according to user manual, despite its name, it disables access to RTC registers as well, and its counterpart is called during RTC initialization on mbed.

```
HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
```